# iOS Firebase: Retrieve and match database code to pass through authentication

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create an authentication security code for admin to login/ register. What I wish to do is login to perform segue if the user pass through the code which exists in firebase database. So now it doesn't works as Error alert box keep popping out event I have enter the correct security code.

[image]

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Security Code?", message: "Please enter your dedicated security code", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: .default) { (_) in
                    let code = alertController.textFields?[0].text

                    let scref=Database.database().reference();

                scref.queryOrdered(byChild: "securitycode").queryEqual(toValue: code).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if (snapshot.exists())
                    {

                        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailText.text!, password: self.passwordText.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                            if user != nil
                            {
                                //if sign in sucessful
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueadmin", sender: self)
                            }   else
                                {
                                    if let myError = error?.localizedDescription{
                                        print(myError)


                                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: myError, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) {
                                            UIAlertAction in
                                            // Insert code to run on button click below
                                            self.printYes()
                                        })
                                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    }else{
                                        print("ERROR")
                                    }
                                }

                            })}


            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (_) in }
            alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
                textField.placeholder = "Enter Code:"
            }


            //adding the action to dialogbox
            alertController.addAction(confirmAction)
            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            //finally presenting the dialog box
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Alright and what's your issue ?

Comment: it doesn't go through even i have entered the correct security code

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be an issue when you query your database.

Try this code :

```
scref.child("securitycode").child(code).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in 
 if (snapshot.exists()) {
    ...//Do your thing
 }
```

With this your aim the reference /securitycode/{code} and if it exists it seems that there is a correct value stored in your database so you can proceed. If not the user can't proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Very careless of me! It because of I didn't structure the data well and forgot to put " " for the data in Firebase.

So the firebase database should be:
[image: The firebase]

And the code shall be:

```
       ref=Database.database().reference().child("securitycode")

        ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "code")
            .queryEqual(toValue: self.textf.text)
            .observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```